# R data.table: sum of vectors in seperate columns

Tags: r, list, vector, data.table

I have a data.table with vectors or actually list with vector inside columns cells i.e.:

```
testDATA <- data.table('COLUMN_1' = list(1:4, 11:14, 21:24),
                       'COLUMN_ABC' = list(5:8, 25:28, 15:18),
                       'COLUMN1342' = list(2:5, 32:35, 22:25))
```

Additionally I have a vector with names of columns which vectors' elements I want to sum i.e.:

```
columnsToSum <- c('COLUMN_ABC', 'COLUMN1342')
```

How can I add column to data.table which will sum vectors' elements from columns defined in columnsToSum so that in the first row I will have vector c(6,8,10,12) ? I know that I can sum two vectors like this:

```
testDATA[, sumCol := list(Map(function(x,y) x + y, get('COLUMN_ABC'), get('COLUMN1342')))]
```

although the thing is that I have all columns which I should sum in columnsToSum vector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you

```
testDATA[, sumCol := Reduce(function(a,b) Map(`+`,a,b), .SD), 
    .SDcols=columnsToSum]
```

We use `.SD` to get a group of columns from the data table, then we use `Reduce()` to sequentially add them up and use `Map()` to add up each of the rows separately. It will work with more than 2 columns

```
columnsToSum <- names(testDATA)
testDATA[, sumCol := Reduce(function(a,b) Map(`+`,a,b), .SD), .SDcols=columnsToSum]
testDATA
#       COLUMN_1  COLUMN_ABC  COLUMN1342          sumCol
# 1:     1,2,3,4     5,6,7,8     2,3,4,5     23,31,39,47
# 2: 11,12,13,14 25,26,27,28 32,33,34,35 193,201,209,217
# 3: 21,22,23,24 15,16,17,18 22,23,24,25 153,161,169,177
```

Comment: thanks! could you explain also why inherits=TRUE is nessesary here?

Comment: It's related to [this issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1712). `get()` and `mget()` have different behaviors as far as where they search for variables.

Comment: thanks a lot! could you also give me a clue if i would have two vectors columnsToSum1 and columnsToSum2 and i want to multiply them as a new column (i.e. first column from columnsToSum1 * first column from columnsToSum2 + second ones etc.? Should I ask new question?

Comment: That's very different. I'd ask a new question. Make sure it can stand on it's own.